# I am making a mod for a game, but i cant figure out where to put the different fields. can someone explain or give me and example?

Tags: c#

I want to put this in my behaviour class, so when an object collides with another it will invoke an event.

documentation for the modding.

[image: Documentation for the collision fields that i want to use.]

This is the code for the object

```
            ModAPI.Register(    
            new Modification()
            {
                OriginalItem = ModAPI.FindSpawnable("Stick"),
                NameOverride = "Ram Stick",
                DescriptionOverride = "Looks like it holds 128 megabytes of memory, wouldn't be useful today.",
                CategoryOverride = ModAPI.FindCategory("Machinery"),
                ThumbnailOverride = ModAPI.LoadSprite("sprites/ramstick_thumb.png"),
                AfterSpawn = (Instance) =>
                {
                    //Sets ramstick sprite when spawned and scales it down
                    Instance.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
                    Instance.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = ModAPI.LoadSprite("sprites/ramstick.png");

                    Instance.AddComponent<RamstickBehavior>();

                    Instance.FixColliders();

                }
            }
```

and this is my behaviour.

```
    public class RamstickBehavior : MonoBehaviour
{

}
```

I am kind of new to C# if anyone could help me set this up it would be appreciated, or give me examples or some pages where i can do research on this, but im not exactly sure where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Collider2D and use OnCollisionEnter, which is automatically called when the collision is detected.

```
public class RamstickBehavior : MonoBehaviour
{
    Collider2D myCollider; // or just add in the editor and/or make this public and drag a collider from the editor

    void Start()
    {
        myCollider = GetComponent<Collider2D>(); // alternatively, from the code like this
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        foreach (ContactPoint contact in collision.contacts)
        {
            // invoke an event
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will the event just execute when it detects collision at all, and how do i set a certain object to it, i don't use an editor as i am coding a mod.?thanks for the help as well!

Comment: Yes, the OnCollisionEnter function will. But coding Unity without using the editor is nearly impossible I think.

Comment: Collider2D is a component, you set it to an object (in Start() ) like this: `Collider2D myCollider = myGameObject.AddComponent(typeof(Collider2D)) as Collider2D;` where `myGameObject` is the game object

Comment: The mod im making is compiled using Roslyn mod compiler, which makes it able to modify games added with a mod api for modding support, thank you though!